# Get and Set attribute values of a class using aspectJ

Tags: aspectj

I am using aspectj to add some field to a existing class and annotate it also.
   I am using load time weaving .

Example  :-  I have a Class customer  in which i am adding 3 string attributes. But my issues is that I have to set some values and get it also before my business call.

I am trying the below approach.
  In my aj file i have added the below, my problem is in the Around pointcut , how do i get the attribute and set the attribute.

```
public String net.customers.PersonCustomer.getOfflineRiskCategory() {
        return OfflineRiskCategory;
}

public void net.customers.PersonCustomer.setOfflineRiskCategory(String offlineRiskCategory) {
        OfflineRiskCategory = offlineRiskCategory;
    }

    public String net.customers.PersonCustomer.getOnlineRiskCategory() {
        return OnlineRiskCategory;
    }

    public void net.customers.PersonCustomer.setOnlineRiskCategory(String onlineRiskCategory) {
        OnlineRiskCategory = onlineRiskCategory;
    }

    public String net.customers.PersonCustomer.getPersonCommercialStatus() {
        return PersonCommercialStatus;
    }

    public void net.customers.PersonCustomer.setPersonCommercialStatus(String personCommercialStatus) {
        PersonCommercialStatus = personCommercialStatus;
    }

    @Around("execution(* net.xxx.xxx.xxx.DataMigration.populateMap(..))")
 public Object invoke(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
  Object arguments[] = joinPoint.getArgs();

  if (arguments != null) {
      HashMap<String, String> hMap = (HashMap) arguments[0]; 
      PersonCustomer cus = (PersonCustomer) arguments[1];

  return joinPoint.proceed();
 }
```

If anyone has ideas please let me know.

regards,
FT

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion, I would avoid mixing code-style aspectj with annotation-style.  Ie- instead of `@Around`, use `around`.

Second, instead of getting the arguments from the joinPoint, you should bind them in the pointcut:

```
Object around(Map map, PersonCustomer cust) : 
    execution(* net.xxx.xxx.xxx.DataMigration.populateMap(Map, PersonCustomer) && args(map, cust) {
  ...
  return proceed(map, cust);
}
```

Now, to answer your question: you also need to use intertype declarations to add new fields to your class, so do something like this:

```
private String net.customers.PersonCustomer.OfflineRiskCategory;
private String net.customers.PersonCustomer.OnlineRiskCategory;
private String net.customers.PersonCustomer.PersonCommercialStatus;
```

Note that the `private` keyword here means private to the aspect, not to the class that you declare it on.